# .NET CORE not loading resource files for different languages

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I cannot load translations in ASP.NET CORE MVC.

My stratup looks like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(
                Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
                opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("sk-SK"),
            new CultureInfo("hu-HU"),
        };

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "sk-SK", uiCulture: "sk-SK");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<UserData, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<IProductService, ProductService>();

        // Repository
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
        services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
        IHostingEnvironment env,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("sk-SK"),
            new CultureInfo("hu-HU"),
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("sk-SK"),
            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });

        //app.UseRequestCulture();

        Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<ProductData, ProductDetailViewModel>();
        });

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
    }
```

and I have Resources file in

```
/Resources/Views/Product/Details.resx
/Resources/Views/Product/Details.sk.resx
/Resources/Views/Product/Details.sk-SK.resx
```

and my Details.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = Localizer["Manufacturer"];
}
```

the problem is that i always get result from Details.resx, not from Details.sk.resx or Details.sk-SK.resx

What I do wrong ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to map a new route in route config.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "cultureRoute",
    template: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },                    
    constraints: new { 
       culture = new RegexRouteConstraint("^[a-z]{2}(?:-[A-Z]{2})?$") });
```

So route path would be like below.
 - /

- /en
- /home
- /es-ES/home
- /home/index
- /es/home/index
- /home/index/123
- /en-US/home/index/123